# Dual boot CentOS7 with Windows 10: Can't boot into CentOS

Tags: centos, dual-boot, grub

I was using CentOS 7 and Windows 10 as a dual boot on system. Everything was working fine till I updated my BIOS using windows. I can't see CentOS on startup. I have changed my hard drive to legacy mode.

Comment: Does the "legacy mode" refer to "legacy IDE" as opposed to AHCI, or to "legacy MBR/BIOS compatibilty support" as opposed to UEFI? And do you know what was the state of this setting before the BIOS update?

Comment: I have tried re-installing grub using bootable CentOS drive by following the instructions on [this link](https://www.tecmint.com/recover-or-rescue-corrupted-grub-boot-loader-in-centos-7/), but I was not able to install the grub. It gives error "/sbin/grub2-install error /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory"

Comment: legacy MBR/BIOS, I can't remember the previous BIOS setting, but CentOS was in EFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Boot device option in the bios and select Linux based boot manager
displayed there your problem will be solved